# how to ad a vertical line to matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to show a vertical line at x='23:30:00'. I have tried x = '23:30' as well. Any ideas?

```
df1 = df1.between_time('19:30','23:59')
df1['high'].plot(kind='line',figsize = (10,5))
plt.axvline(x='23:30:00', color = 'r')
plt.show()
```

[image: Add vert line to chart at 23:30]

Comment: Have you tried using an actual datetime instance as x variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass the point you want the line in datetime format instead of the string you pass. Simply:

```
#datetime format input
plt.axvline(x= datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 25,23,30), color = 'r')
```

Result on a random dataframe:

[image]

Comment: I must be missing something, i get an error 'name datetime is not defined', i would like to just input the time and that's where the vertical line would be?

Comment: You need to import datetime library first. Write [ import datatime ]  before using it.

Comment: @Ross Demtschyna Please accept and close this question if you solved your problem