# Adding x major grid line on specific date

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a stock data plot, only wanted to tick major line on specific date 
 specificdate = '2018-03-16T00:00:00.000000000'

```
daysFmt = DateFormatter("%d %b")
ax = plt.axes()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(specificdate)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(daysFmt)
```

When i add the above code it shows blank page.

Comment: Do you want to have a single vertical line at a specific date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to ad a vertical line to matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399192/how-to-ad-a-vertical-line-to-matplotlib)